# Does WillTerminate method fire when stopping an application in MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am trying to find out if the WillTerminate method of the UIApplicationDelegate class fire when the application is terminated in MonoDevelop? I ask this because I have set up my application to close the database connections when the application terminates, and it does not seem like this is happening when I stop the application from MonoDevelop.

I know that iphone applications should not have a "close" function, but is there some way of simulating an application close on the simulator so I can test the execution of the WillTerminate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not, it forcibly exits the application.  To test the behaviour you can add:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

To your Info.plist, and click the home button.

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. When I first tried adding this value to the plist I clicked _Add Child_ button,  added the key _UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend_ and typed _true_ as the value, and it didn't work. But then I selected the value and clicked _edit_, _Value Type_ and chose _Boolean_ so that a checbox with a tick in it appeared. I then saved and ran the application and the WillTerminate method executed when I clicked home. So, in summarize, it worked... but hopefully this extra info helps another noobie like me... hehe. :) Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Thanks BruceHill. If someone needs help, in Monodevelop, this is equivalent to "Application does not run in background" key while editing the keys in advanced setting tab of pList file.